# How to see the stored char ascii value in sql

Tags: database, oracle

i am trying to see the stored char ASCII value in memory but it will only show the first char ASCII. I want to complete char structure stored in memory 
ex coloumn name char(10)
 and i am passing abc 
so it should display the int array as follow
 67 68 69 32 32 32 32 32 32 32

Here 32 for Space

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you edit your question please to show the actual sql statement you are using and the results you are getting. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to see the stored bytes then use `dump()`, which will show you in decimal or hexadecimal or even octal if you prefer. Bob's method to extract just the bytes from that output is useful, and you could optionally replace the commas with spaces if that's important.

If you did want to see the hex values you could also do:

```
select name,
  cast(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(name) as varchar2(20)) as ascii
from your_table;

NAME       ASCII                         
---------- ------------------------------
abc        61626320202020202020
```

And as an alternative to get the decimal values, you could use a hierarchical query:

```
select name,
  listagg(ascii(substr(name, level, 1)), ' ') within group (order by level) as ascii
from your_table
connect by level <= length(name)
group by name;

NAME       ASCII                         
---------- ------------------------------
abc        97 98 99 32 32 32 32 32 32 32
```

though that gets a bit messy with multiple rows to deal with, and is doing quite a bit of work compared to simply dumping the value.

A slight variation on Bob's just to get exactly the format you showed (which may not actually matter of course):

```
select name,
  dump(name) as dumped,
  trim(regexp_replace(dump(name), '((.*:)|,)', ' ')) as ascii
from your_table;

NAME       DUMPED                                        ASCII                         
---------- --------------------------------------------- ------------------------------
abc        Typ=96 Len=10: 97,98,99,32,32,32,32,32,32,32  97 98 99 32 32 32 32 32 32 32
```

(It isn't really ASCII unless your character set is US7ASCII; it's the decimal representation in the database character set... but that distinction is usually ignored. These will all give you values (> 127) for non-ASCII characters too though.)

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to `DUMP` the string, then grab the list of byte codes from the output:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(DUMP('a b c d'), ':.*'), 3) FROM DUAL;
```

In your case you'd want to do something like

```
SELECT SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(DUMP(YOUR_COLUMN_NAME), ':.*'), 3)
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97d42/1)

Best of luck.